# How wide can an image be before it's resized?

Tags: support

When adding images to questions and answers, what is the maximum width it can be before it gets resized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

640px is the width of the images. So that's the size they get scaled down to.

As from this CSS rule:

```
.post-text img {
  max-width : 640px;
}
```

Please note that this also illustrates that images are not scaled down server-side. They are always original size, just displayed smaller.

Of course, I myself have that overwritten, see [Images can be pushed outside the boundaries of a post by using nested lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143973/images-can-be-pushed-outside-the-boundaries-of-a-post-by-using-nested-lists)

Comment: this appears to be too large. I'll add a pictured of a 660px circle to my question so you can see.

Comment: @Louis: You're right. I corrected my post